# Authorization Flow Access and Refresh Tokens

Tags: identityserver4

Using Authorization Code does the middleware that intercepts signin-oidc exchange the authorization code for the access tokens or do I have to do this programatically? If the middleware does it, then were can I find the access and refresh tokens?

Or do I have to implement my own redirect url and code and capture the returned code and exchange it with the access tokens using RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync?

Comment: This doesn't make sense without more context of what you are using to implement authority, resource, client sides.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not have to implement the part to obtain the tokens this is handled by the handler,  But you need a callback to handle the signin, storing claims and creating a login.  Here is a primitive example of how to Obtain the Access Tokens:

**EDIT**

I will use Google as an example because I have the code on hand but the IdentityServer OAuth should be the same, seeing as they Extend OAuthHandler

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
   //Add your identity Server schema etc
})
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Google:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"];
})
```

And in your Authentication controller:

```
[HttpPost("ExternalLogin")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}

[HttpGet("ExternalLoginCallback")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string     remoteError = null)
{
    if (remoteError != null)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");
    }
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        //It throws here, since there are no tokens 
        throw new Exception("Error: could not find user tokens");
    }

    //Handle the rest of authentication
}
```

What Happens? You have a button pointing to your External Login Provider "Google" as the provider.

You're redirected to the Google login page, and you login.

Google server redirects you back to you're domain and /google-signin (by default hidden in the handle) With the Authorization Code

The Google handler then uses the authorization code along with your secret to obtain the tokens

If you specify to save Tokens, in the OAuth Options, Tokens from the response will be saved. Along with some basic claims obtained from the user info endpoint.

You're then redirected to the External Login callback:

```
_signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

Will obtain the saved tokens.

So to answer your question. The handler will take care of saving tokens (If you specify it to).  And you can obtain them from the signInManger if needed.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg the authorization code flow is that same for all handlers. I used google as an example but Consuming IdentityServer4 is just an extension of the OAuthHandler

Comment: ThanksSo, signin-oidc is supposed to call into a callback function that I'm supposed to implement (just using IdentityServer4 with the starter UI)

Comment: The external login will call challenge and create a redirect to the externallogincallback,  this code was modified from the identity server 4  examples I just tried to break down the steps for you.  If it's been useful please remember to upvote